# Getting an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query') while connecting to microsoft access db

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-connection, ms-access-data-macro, micr

```
const databasePath = 'C:\\Users\\2250689\\Downloads\\trailRMTool.accdb';     
 
const connection = odbc.connect(`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=${databasePath}`, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }
  const sqlQuery = 'SELECT Name FROM RMData';
  connection.query(sqlQuery, (queryError, result) => {
    if (queryError) {
      console.error('Error executing query:', queryError);
    } else {
      console.log('Query result:', result);
    }

    connection.close((closeError) => {
      if (closeError) {
        console.error('Error closing the database connection:', closeError);
      } else {
        console.log('Database connection closed.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

it is also showing that there is an error in node_modules file also,
I tried querying one column as well but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access `connection` object but it's undefined, because you are using callback API when calling `odbc.connect((err) => {})`.

To solve the problem:

a) Use async/await API instead of callback API

b) Remove initialisation of const connection and add agrument `connection` in the callback. Code:

```
const databasePath = 'C:\\Users\\2250689\\Downloads\\trailRMTool.accdb';
const fullPath = `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=${databasePath}`
odbc.connect(fullPath, (err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
    return;
  }
  const sqlQuery = 'SELECT Name FROM RMData';
  connection.query(sqlQuery, (queryError, result) => {
    if (queryError) {
      console.error('Error executing query:', queryError);
    } else {
      console.log('Query result:', result);
    }
    connection.close((closeError) => {
      if (closeError) {
        console.error('Error closing the database connection:', closeError);
      } else {
        console.log('Database connection closed.');
      }
    });
  });
});
```